# Having trouble with the `ChainSpec` Type

Tags: chainspec, genesis, substrate-node

I've updated the `ChainSpec` type from:

```rs
pub type ChainSpec = sc_service::GenericChainSpec<GenesisConfig, Extensions>;
```

to

```rs
pub type ChainSpec = sc_service::GenericChainSpec<Result<GenesisConfig, String>, Extensions>;
```

But, I'm getting this error in the `command.rs`:

```rs
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Result<node_template_runtime::GenesisConfig, std::string::String>: BuildStorage` is not satisfied
  --> node/src/command.rs:49:12
   |
49 |         Ok(Box::new(spec))
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `BuildStorage` is not implemented for `Result<node_template_runtime::GenesisConfig, std::string::String>`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `BuildStorage`:
             ()
             GenericChainSpec<G, E>
             node_template_runtime::GenesisConfig
             sp_runtime::Storage
   = note: required for `Result<node_template_runtime::GenesisConfig, std::string::String>` to implement `RuntimeGenesis`
   = note: required for `GenericChainSpec<Result<node_template_runtime::GenesisConfig, std::string::String>, Extensions>` to implement `sc_chain_spec::ChainSpec`
   = note: required for the cast from `GenericChainSpec<Result<node_template_runtime::GenesisConfig, std::string::String>, Extensions>` to the object type `dyn sc_chain_spec::ChainSpec`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

Is there a way to `unwrap` the `ChainSpec` in the `load_spec()` method?

Comment: Please show your code. 

`sc_service::GenericChainSpec<Result<GenesisConfig, String>` this makes no real sense. The underlying issue is that `Result<GenesisConfig>` doesn't implement the `BuildStorage` trait.